# Android 4.1 copy files

Tags: android, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I'm developing an app that backs up and restores the saves of all Angry Birds Versions.
For devices with Android 4.0 or higher I've written a simple input/output file stream, and it works.
On device with Android 4.1 or higher (due probably to the increased security) the Angry Birds saves require more permissions to be copied from my app (`rwx` isn't enough). Is there a way to change the permission adding root access in my app or is there a solution without adding root?

Answer (score 0):

When files are stored to the internal storage, they are private by default. You won't be able to read them unless the app created them with MODE_WORLD_READABLE. The only shortcut around that is to require rooted devices and that your app be granted super user status.